# Comparar dos fechas array en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Buen día a todos. Tengo en una tabla dos columnas fecha_entrega y fecha_devolución
necesito validar si la fecha_entrega es menor a la fecha_devolución con un mensaje.
El problema los campos son arrays.

```
'<td ><input class="form-control" required  type="text" name="FechaEntrega[]" id="FechaEntrega[]" value="'+FechaEntrega+'" tabindex="1"></td>'+
```

el otro campo es:

```
 var FechaDevolucion = [$("#fecha_devolucion_busqueda").val()];
'<td ><input class="form-control" required  type="date" name="FechaDevolucion[]" id="FechaDevolucion[]" value="'+FechaDevolucion[0]+'" readonly="false"></td>'+
```

intente de varias maneras y no logro resolverlo.

Answer (score 0):

Para comparar dos fechas en js podrías hacer una función en js que dispare una alerta en caso de que la fecha devolución sea anterior a entrega.

```
<script>
      function validarFechas() {
        var fech1 = document.getElementById("FechaEntrega[]").value;
        var fech2 = document.getElementById("FechaDevolucion[]").value;

      if((Date.parse(fech1)) > (Date.parse(fech2))){
         alert(‘La fecha de devolución no puede ser anterior que la fecha entrega’);
         }
      }
</script>
```

Ahora podes llamarla desde la accion de cualquier button/input. Por ejemplo el evento onchange de FechaDevolucion:

```
'<td ><input class="form-control" required  type="date" name="FechaDevolucion[]" id="FechaDevolucion[]" value="'+FechaDevolucion[0]+'" readonly="false" onchange="validarFechas();"></td>'
```

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la información, funciona bien pero tengo una tabla de 20 registros digamos el código funciona bien pero solo valida la primera fila y las siguientes filas no. es una tabla con los inputs[]  al final lo actualizo simultáneamente.